# When filter meets delegate

Tags: jquery

Delegate needs element and selector to be specified.
I have a regular expression filter

```
$(".R, .G").filter(function () {
    return !/.+\.(gif|jpg|png|tiff|svg)$/i.exec($(this).attr("href"));
})
```

and I want to bind the filtered elements created on-fly with click() using delegate. the code should be

```
$(".R, .G").filter(function () {
    return !/.+\.(gif|jpg|png|tiff|svg)$/i.exec($(this).attr("href"));
}).delegate("?", "click", function(){...});
```

The filtered out element is what I want to bind. What should I specify for the selector? "this"? "null"?

I cannot emphasise enough the difference between delegate and on. people who suggest on please try the difference between

```
$("p").on("click", function () {
    $(this).text("clicked");
});

$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).after($("<p>").text("hellowld;|"))
});
```

and

```
$("body").delegate("p", "click", function () {
    $(this).text("clicked");
});

$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).after($("<p>").text("hellowld;|"))
});
```

**Last Edit**:
as nnnnnn, on and delegate are the same, I guess.

After tests of all solutions here, Only Arun P Johny's solution work here.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible, one possible solution will is to write a custom filter expression

Comment: _"I cannot emphasise enough the difference between delegate and on."_ - The `.on()` method can do everything the `.delegate()` method can do. If you bother to read the `.on()` documentation you'll find that  `$("body").on("click", "p", function() {...});` is equivalent to `$("body").delegate("p","click", function {...});`.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to write a custom expression to filter it

```
jQuery.expr[':'].mycustom = function(elem) {
    return !/.+\.(gif|jpg|png|tiff|svg)$/i.exec(elem.href);
};

$(document).delegate('.R:mycustom, .G:mycustom', 'click', function(){
    console.log('clicked', this.href);
    return false;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TzGgV/)

Or with `.on()`: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TzGgV/2/)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
So, here's an approach that will add a class to it, called "myClass" and now you can use `"myClass"` for the `on` event and should work for any new elements that get created as well.

```
$(".R, .G").filter(function () {
        return !/.+\.(gif|jpg|png|tiff|svg)$/i.exec($(this).attr("href"));
    }).addClass("myClass");

$("body").on("click", ".myClass", function(event) {
// Do something...
});
```

So, maybe this will work and maybe not...  I dunno, but if you add a class called, `myClass` to all matched elements, it should now be able to be manipulated via the class.  You might want to trigger the filter code within a function and call that function when you need it to be called to repopulate the "myClass" class elements on the page.

Comment: The difference between delegate and on is that on only binds the current elements. delegate binds current elements and created from now on.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, they recommend that you use `on` instead of `delegate` or `live`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Looking at your latest edit, and you are not using `.on` correctly... In order to use `delegated` events, you need 3 parameters in `.on`, not 2.  These are the differences between delegated and non-delegated.  If you look at my code examples, there are 3 parameters being used in the `.on` event function, thus forcing it to be `delegated`

Comment: That second example will give an error: jQuery objects don't have a `.body` property. The first example won't apply the filter to elements added dynamically later.

Comment: again, my bad.
will delegate become deprecated?

Comment: this solution does not work. I have just tried. I think the reason is that the filter only works once. When new elements come, they need a new filter.

Comment: Why not just add a class to it and than use `on` for the class?

Comment: I edited my answer for adding a class to it called `myClass`, this should work now!

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$(".R, .G").filter(function () {
    return !/.+\.(gif|jpg|png|tiff|svg)$/i.exec($(this).attr("href"));
}).on("click", function(){...});
```

Comment: The problem is only the filtered elements at the moment are bound. The elements created after are not.